# How do you add notifcationhubs library

Tags: azure-notificationhub, azure-functions

How do you include notificationhubs library to azure function? This is my attempt and it doesn't work

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
   Notification a;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll add NotificationHubs to the list of built in assemblies, but for now you can add a package reference to NoficationHubs by adding a **project.json** file for your Function (as described in the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/)).

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs": "1.0.5"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

With that in place you can add a using statement for NotificationHubs, e.g.:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req, 
    TraceWriter log, 
    out Notification notification)
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    // TODO
    notification = null;

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```